# Unexpected output while using %u specifier with float variable?

Tags: c, floating-point, unsigned

Unexpected output while using %u specifier with float variable? my code is below please help me to understand?

```
 int main()
  {
   float f=9.8;
   printf("%u",f); //unexpected out put what will be out put and why please help to understand ?
  }
```

Comment: This isn't remotely unexpected. What you're trying to do is nonsense, what would you expect to happen? `%u` expects an `unsigned int`, you can't pass a `float` to it and expect it to work. `printf("%u", (unsigned) f);` would be OK.

Comment: This is just a stupid question.  I cannot think of any other way to describe it.  Any printf documentation will reveal such madness for what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `u` format specifier means `unsigned int`.  Your call to `printf` doesn't know to convert your `float` into an unsigned int, so `printf` just reinterprets the bits of your `float` as an `unsigned int`.

If you really do want to output it as an integer, you need to explicitly cast it:

```
printf("%u", (unsigned int) f);
```

Or if you meant to output it as floating point, use `%f`:

```
printf("%f", f);
```